# How to fix error on deployment with Glassfish 3

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I'm developing a JavaEE application on Glasfish Application Server. I'm developing so I'm continously deployig/undeploying the application.

Everything worked great until a few hours ago when I got this error while deploying:

```
INFO: ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.fam.declarationreglementaire.service.comparaison.TableauComparaisonDecRegService
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1518)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1368)
... 59 more

GRAVE: PWC1306: Startup of context /declaration-reglementaire-serviceweb failed due to previous errors
GRAVE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started


GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.fam.declarationreglementaire.service.comparaison.TableauComparaisonDecRegService


ATTENTION: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;


 GRAVE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;


GRAVE: Exception while loading the app

GRAVE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfr/fam/declarationreglementaire/service/comparaison/TableauComparaisonDecRegService;
```

I searched the web but seems no one has encountered the same problem.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Try to rebuild/clean build your project before deploying it. It seems like there is something wrong with your     fr.fam.declarationreglementaire.service.comparaison.TableauComparaisonDecRegService class.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to rebuild/clean build but it doesn't resolve the problem, and everything has worked great after that I didn't changed fr.fam.declarationreglementaire.service.comparaison.TableauComparaisonDecRegServ‌​ice

Comment: Did you try to restart Glassfish?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work too ! And I restarted the pc and springtool Suite !